# How to make a full decimal point for a calculator on swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've just started to study Xcode.
I've made all digits and math signs, but have no clue how to make a dot for calculator.

This is what I've done (deleted some repeating parts of math operations):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberFromScreen: Double = 0
    var firstNum: Double = 0
    var operation: Int = 0
    var mathSign: Bool = false


    @IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!
    @IBAction func digits(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if mathSign == true {
            result.text = String (sender.tag)
            mathSign = false
        }
        else {
            result.text = result.text! + String (sender.tag)
        }

        numberFromScreen = Double (result.text!)!
    }
    @IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if result.text != "" && sender.tag != 10 && sender.tag != 15 {
        firstNum = Double (result.text!)!

            if sender.tag == 11 {// divine
                result.text = "/"

            }


            operation = sender.tag
            mathSign = true
        }
        else if sender.tag == 15 {// calculate
            if operation == 11 {
                result.text = String(firstNum / numberFromScreen)
            }
        }
        else if sender.tag == 10 {
            result.text = ""
            firstNum = 0
            numberFromScreen = 0
            operation = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really hard to read with all of these cryptic `tag` values (we usually hook up `@IBOutlet` references with meaningful names which makes the code much easier to follow), at least for all the non-digit buttons. I’d also replace `operation` with an enumeration with meaningful names, again so we can see what’s you’re trying to do. I’d also hookup the various buttons to individual `@IBAction` methods, again giving them meaningful names. This code is really hard to follow.

Comment: In answer to your question, at the bare minimum, the decimal point button would just add a decimal point to the end of `result.text`. You might want to keep track of whether there is already a decimal point there, though, because you want to avoid a user entering “.....4” or “1.2.3” (especially with that `!` force cast operator at `Double(result.text)!`).

Answer (score 0):

In your case using the **[NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)** would be a good option.

You can define it as follows:

```
private var formater: NumberFormatter {
    let formater = NumberFormatter()
    formater.maximumIntegerDigits = 9  // Change this value
    formater.maximumFractionDigits = 9 // Change this value 
    formater.minimumFractionDigits = 9 // Change this value 
    formater.minimumIntegerDigits = 1  // Change this value 
    formater.maximumIntegerDigits = 9  // Change this value 
    formater.groupingSeparator = " "
    formater.locale = Locale.current
    formater.numberStyle = .decimal
    return formater
}
```

And when you are setting the result to the label, you can go:

```
result.text = formater.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(value: yourValue))
```

If you are making a calculator I would recommend you that for bigger numbers or for numbers with many decimal places, you set the `numberStyle` property to `.scientific`.